# Is it possible to ignore one node when using CamelCaseStyle in simple-framework

Tags: java, xml, serialization, simple-framework

When i serialize my java object by simple, i met a camel case issue. What i use CamelCaseStyle, all nodes' name will be camelcased, but i need a exception on one specific node, how can i set it? for example, my code is:

```
public class Message {
    String toUserName;
    @ElementList(entry="item")
    LinkedList<Article> articles;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.toUserName = "xxx";
            Article item = new Article();
            item.title = "aaa";
            LinkedList<Article> list = new LinkedList<Article>();
            list.add(item);
            msg.articles = list;

            Style style = new CamelCaseStyle();
            Format format = new Format(style);
            Serializer serializer = new Persister(format);
            OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                    serializer.write(msg, os);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.print(os);
    }
}
```

The generated xml is:

```
<Message>
 <ToUserName>xxx</ToUserName>
 <Articles>
  <Item>
     <Title>aaa</Title>
  </Item>
 </Articles>
</Message>
```

What i want is:

```
<Message>
 <ToUserName>xxx</ToUserName>
 <Articles>
  <item>
     <Title>aaa</Title>
  </item>
 </Articles>
</Message>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, take a look at the setElement method of the CamelCaseStyle, set "item" to "item" like so

```
camelCaseStyle.setElement("item", "item")
```